# Highlight Pipe does not fade after clearing the search text

Tags: angular, angular-material, pipe

I am using [this sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nue8pb-fwqdsc?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.ts) that I found for creating a pipe to highlight the search text in a mat-autocomplete. The highlighted part works fine, but once I clear the search, the highlight still remains in the drop down. This is not expected behavior. I want the highlight to go away once the search is cleared.

Please help me fix this.

Comment: What does your code look like? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this-

**.html** file

```
<input matInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl" (keyup)="onStateKeyup()">
```

**.ts** file

```
onStateKeyup() {
    this.toHighlight = this.stateCtrl.value;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You can just change your constructor, I think the following code will help you

```
 constructor() {
    this.stateCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.filteredStates = this.stateCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(state => this.filterStates(state))
      );
  }

  filterStates(name: string) {
    this.toHighlight = name;
    return this.states.filter(state =>
      state.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-autocomplete-highlight)

Comment: I have an additional functionality in my dropdown which is not part of the code posted here. It couldn't support that. However, thank you for your help.